# What would happen to the frequency of the emitted EMR as the electron spirals into the nucleus?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, atomic-physics

I can't think a formula to actually prove what happens... maybe $=v^2/$? Is the energy of the emitted EMR is higher due to the acceleration of the electron being higher? I am asking this in the context of the Rutherford planetary model of the atom by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for circular motion, the centripetal acceleration is proportional to $v^2/r$ and is provided by the Coulomb force, which is proportional to $r^{-2}$.

Thus the power emitted as radiation goes as the square of the acceleration and would be proportional to $r^{-4}$.

Since $\omega = v/r = r^{-1/2}\sqrt{v^2/r}$ and we know $v^2/r\propto r^{-2}$ from above,
then the frequency of the orbit (and hence the frequency of the emitted regions)
$$\omega \propto r^{-3/2}.$$

Comment: I think this is synchrotron radiation so the typical frequency can be large compared to the orbit frequency owing to relativistic boost (estimate it by finding pulse width $\tau$ and then freq spread is of order $1/\tau$.)

Answer (score 0):

As the electron spirals in, its period of revolution decreases, as one can see from Kepler’s Third Law $T^2\propto a^3$. (This law applies to any inverse-square central force, not just gravity.) So the electron’s frequency of revolution increases, and thus the frequency of the electromagnetic radiation that it emits increases as well.